# Discord bot won't send my message to server but prints it in terminal

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@bot.command(name="complete")
async def _command(ctx):

    await ctx.send(f"Which task did you complete?\n" + ("-"*20) + "\n")
    dictDailyTasks = { i : dailyTasks[i] for i in range(0, len(dailyTasks) ) }
    for key, value in dictDailyTasks.items():
         print(key,value)

Output:
0 RUN
1 WORKOUT
```

My code works when I print the key, value to console, however, when I try to send it to my channel nothing happens.

```
@bot.command(name="complete")
async def _command(ctx):

    await ctx.send(f"Which task did you complete?\n" + ("-"*20) + "\n")
    dictDailyTasks = { i : dailyTasks[i] for i in range(0, len(dailyTasks) ) }
    for key, value in dictDailyTasks.items():
         await ctx.send(key, value)
```

Any idea why this is happening? I feel like its a silly mistake I am overlooking! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is because `print()` can take multiple arguments and print all of them out, while `send` only takes 1 (the content to send). If you want to send them as a pair instead of separately, either send a tuple or format them in a string.

```py
await ctx.send(f"({key}, {value})")
```